# Make site page content load first before Footer component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have used setTimeOut on Footer Component but the footer still loads first on all the pages. How do I make sure the dynamic content loads first before the footer.

```js
function Footer({ rawdata, theme, locale }) {
  const [isFooter, setFooter] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setFooter(true), 3000); // let page load first before footer
  }, []);
  if (isFooter) {
    return ()
```

The main component where the footer is used

```
import ScrollToTop from 'react-router-scroll-top';
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
...
...
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <>
          {navbarState.data !== false && (
            <Navbar
              isUserAuthenticated={isUserAuthenticated}
              locale={locale}
            />
          )}
          <ScrollToTop>{renderRoutes(route.routes)}</ScrollToTop>
          <Footer rawdata={footerState.data} locale={locale} />
        </>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more details including code base ?

Comment: Add some flags to global context and enables those flags only after all you other components gets loaded..the load your footer only when all flags are ok. Read more about context and reducer here... https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

How is the dynamic content being loaded? Are you doing an ajax call? If so, you can change a state variable to show the footer when the ajax returns. You should put the `isFooter` variable (would `showFooter` be a better name?) in a place where both components can see it: either a common ancestor component or maybe React Context. `isFooter` will then be passed as a prop of `Footer`. Or you could check `isFooter` in the parent component and not render `Footer` at all while `isFooter` is false.

Comment: Thanks, @neal-burns. `showFooter` is definitely a better name. The content is loaded in via `react-router-config`. I'll update the code snippet to give more context

Comment: Is there an ajax call happening in a deeper component that's triggered by `renderRoutes()`? Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with `react-router-config` and I can't see an event to hook into in the code you've posted.